# Determine the Initial Probabilities of an HMM

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, probability, hidden-markov-models, markov-chains

So I have managed to estimate most of the parameters in a particular `Hidden Markov Model (HMM)` given the learn dataset. These parameters are: the `emission probabilities` of the hidden states and the `transition matrix` $P$ of the Markov chain. I used `Gibbs sampling` for the learning. Now there is one set of parameters that is still missing that is the initial probabilities $\pi$ (probability distribution of where the chain starts) and I want to deduce it from the learned parameters. How can I do it?

Also, is it true that $\pi$ is the same as the stationary probability distribution of $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a special [start] token. You then know that this will always be the first token, and transitions from the [start] token to other words are learned in the model.

The stationary distribution of the Markov chain is the marginal distribution of $P$.

Comment: I don't think this answered the poster's question. He asked about $\pi$. The answer is for $P$. Did I misread something?

Answer (score 0):

I have been puzzled by the same question for the past few days. As far as I can tell, from all the papers I surveyed, PI is dependent on the 1st output in the sampled sequence. Another word, no matter which derivation you use, the answer will differ depending on the sampled sequence. I therefore believe, this is more a frequentist problem. You must perform actual experiments, and average your answers over the data obtained from them.